# Is it possible to give static IP to clients in pfsense

Tags: dhcp, pfsense, static-ip

I am using pfsense and it provides an IP address to all clients.
Is there any option in there so that I can define the client IP address based upon their MAC address, so that I can measure how much they have downloaded.

Comment: Just to note: this is not a static IP, it is a DHCP reservation. Any additional DHCP options besides the standard IP, gateway, and netmask are still passed to the reserved clients.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Services -> DHCP Server. Then add entries to the table at the bottom of the page.